# How to Get Field Name(Capability Name) from GetFilter Method of powerBi using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

We are creating Visuals using Power BI API Client(JavaScript).Once it is created I want to pre populate all selected Capabilities and filters in another view.I used Visual.getFilters() method to get all pre selected filters but in each item I am not getting the capability to which it belongs,Is there is any way to get capability name with each filter.
for example

I selected bellow properties for creating a visual

Visual Type = Funnel

Capabilities

1 Group = Group1

2 Values = value1

after saving this visual when we execute getFilters(),we are getting this two objects but it does not contains Capability names like Group/Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the capability names in each filter using `getFilters()`, we can get the Capability Names by using `getCapabilities`. To get the capability names, follow the below steps:

1. Create an authoring page:

```js
window.authoringPage = await report.addPage(pageName);
```

2. Create a visual using `Create a visual` API:

```js
const createVisualResponse = await page.createVisual('Visual_Name');
const visual = createVisualResponse.visual;
```

3. Get the applied filters using `getFilters()`:

```js
const filters = await visual.getFilters();
```

We didn't get capabilities of each filter in filters object

[image]

4. Get the Capability Names by using `getCapabilities`:

```js
const capabilities = await visual.getCapabilities();
```

[image]

Find the references and the sample code here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-authoring-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-add-visual
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/get-visual-capabilities